# How to write preinstall script for packagemaker for Mac os

Tags: macos, packagemaker

Hi I am using package-maker of Mac OS to create installer package for Mac OS. I gave created a simple installer package it worked fine. But I want to create a new folder under /Applications directory under which myApplication.app file will be installed. So I need to create a pre-install script which will create folder before my application is installed. then install the application in that directory. But I do not know how to write pre-install script to create a folder under /Applications directory. 
please help me.

I need all of your help to create pre-install script to create a folder under /Applications directory

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a directory, you could have the following preflight or preinstall script:

```
#!/bin/sh
mkdir "/Applications/My Directory"
```

Put that into a file (named `preflight` or `preinstall`) and then make it executable by typing in the terminal: `chmod a+x preflight` (or `preinstall`).